# Creating a Custom Action in an EntitySetController

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an oData application in .Net 4.5.  oData end points are working fine, but I want to create a custom action on the controller to set a flag on a Customer record when given an email address.

Here is my client code (using AngularJS):

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/odata/Customers/SetAlertFlag',
        data: { 'email': 'test@test.com'}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // ...
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // ...
    });
```

Here is my server code:

```
public class CustomersController : EntitySetController<Customer, int>
{
    private DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

    // ... other generated methods here


    // my custom method
    [HttpPut]
    public Boolean SetAlertFlag([FromBody] string email)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The server method never gets called.  When I type this URL in the browser `http://localhost:60903/odata/Customers/SetAlertFlag` I get this error:  "Invalid action detected. 'SetAlertFlag' is not an action that can bind to 'Collection([Skirts.Models.Customer Nullable=False])'."

Can EntitySetController classes not have custom methods?  How else should I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actions in OData use a specific format, and need to be POST. You need to:

Add the action to the EDM:

```
ActionConfiguration action = modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Collection.Action("SetAlertFlag");
action.Parameter<string>("email");
```

Declare the action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public int SetAlertFlag(ODataActionParameters parameters) 
{ 
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    string email = (string)parameters["email"];
}
```

Invoke the action something like this:

```
POST http://localhost/odata/Customers/SetAlertFlag
Content-Type: application/json

{"email":"foo"}
```

Read more here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-actions

(I just typed these code snippets, so may be some errors, but that's the idea.)

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks you!  I searched for hours and did not come that web page.  One question... It is little out of the way to add that new action to the ModelBuilder.  Is it recommended to "dirty" up the oData controller (EntitySetController) with these custom actions or should I just create a separate ApiController class for handling all of them?

Comment: Web API lets you mix OData and non-OData controllers, so it really depends if you want a pure OData endpoint. You could create a separate ApiController, but then you lose the benefits of OData (e.g., metadata, links on entities)

Comment: "Actions in OData use a specific format, and need to be POST" one sentence solve all issues, better than the link you give. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MikeWasson These facts about OData actions should really be pointed out in the ASP.NET article you linked to. I just tried creating a custom GET action and failed in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You are using POST in AngularJS, but have [HttpPut] attribute on .NET method. You need to use either POST or PUT on both sides.